# Can I fight the 4 Ubers in single player or non-ladder battle.net?

Tags: diablo-ii

I have defeated Diablo 2 LoD in Hell mode and can't get a large enough crew together to help improve the pop rates on Keys or SoJs to get the different Ubers to spawn (I realize I am asking about 2 different quests).

This is the only content I haven't seen and I would like to try it out before I start D3 as I will probably stop playing D2 after.

Is there a way to experience this game play in single or non-ladder Diablo 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Pandemonium event can only be undertaken on the Ladder and Non-Ladder Battle.net realms and is not functional in single player or LAN games... without a [mod](http://diablorealm.net/index.php?showtopic=23159).

Comment: +1. That mod is actually really useful. Also if you want to test ladder-only runewords on single-player...

Answer (score 3):

Both the [Pandemonium Event](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Pandemonium_Event) (Ubers) and [Uber Diablo](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Uber_Diablo) (Dclone) can be fought on the BattleNet Realms (ladder and non-ladder), but not on Single Player.